# See statistics of views loaded in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I want to optimize the code of my Rails-apps that I run on Heroku. For that purpose I would like to get data/stats over how many times a certain view has been loaded. I.e. not how many times a certain page based on a view.

YES: products#show (total views)
NO: products/this-product-123 (which can easily be seen in Google Analytics)

Is there a view or a smart plugin to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) gem.

I have used it for couple of applications, however this is helpful, if you want to track and store the data, but you can use it to get the request count of it for every view.